# How do I always view a list of compiler warnings in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, settings, compiler-warnings

I'm on IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.6, wholly new to Java, so I apologize if this question is trivial or misguided.

From my days of Visual Studio, I'm expecting to see a clear list of errors and warnings (regardless whether the compilation succeeded or not), but instead what I see are "Information" messages, and only after manually opening the Messages pane. I do see warnings highlighted in code, which I can mouseover and expand, but I'm wondering why I don't see a consolidated list somewhere.

[image]

I searched around and covered all the basics I think—I found out that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> brings up the Messages pane, I verified that "Hide Warnings..." was untoggled, etc. I tried checking the "Build project automatically" setting as well.

Regardless, I just don't see an intuitive list of warnings. What am I missing? Perhaps I'm looking for something obsolete, and I should get with a new workflow?

---

#### Edit

Okay, I've found what I'm looking for by going to Analyze > Inspect Code...

Once inspected, I can reopen the Inspection Analysis from the Tool Windows menu.

I guess the refined question is: **Is there a way to always inspect code along with building?**

Any insight as to why it's not that way by default?

Comment: Feel free to vote for the related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-68854

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Eclipse compiler for this:

`File > Settings` and go to `Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler`

where you can pick `Eclipse` from the `Use compiler` dropdown.

Also see [IntelliJ Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/java-compiler.html#javac_eclipse) on this.

Answer (score 0):

For now I went to `File > Settings > Keymap` and

1. mapped `Main > Analyze > Inspect Code...` to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, and
2. mapped `Tool Windows > Inspection Results` to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>.

Not sure how to force `Build` to do this automatically.

Leaving this question open in case someone has a better answer / suggestion for workflow.